# set src property in view to a url outside of the MVC3 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to create an application that will display images that are stored locally on the webserver. Here is what I have in my view, note that "entry" are absolute addresses like `"C:\Images\Image1.jpg"`. However, when I run it, I get `"Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Images/ImageName.jpg"` in the console log. So maybe it tries to access the image on the client. How do I tell my view to access the local webserver path and not look for the image source on the client? Please note that moving the images into project directory is not an option, because the images are stored on a different drive on the webserver.

```
<!-- language: c# -->
@model List<String>
<div style="height: 500px; overflow:scroll;">
<h2>
    ScreenShots for testMachine</h2>

@foreach (var entry in Model)
{          
   <div class="nailthumb-container square-thumb">
   <img alt="screenshot" src="@Url.Content(entry)" /> 

</div>
}
</div>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You cannot directly serve images outside of your ASP.NET MVC 3 application to the client. That would be a huge security vulnerability if the client could access arbitrary files on your server.

You will need to write a controller action that will return them and then point your `src` property of your `<img>` tags to this controller action.

```
public class ImagesController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult SomeImage()
    {
        return File(@"C:\Images\foo.jpg", "image/jpeg");
    }
}
```

and inside your view:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("SomeImage", "Images")" alt="" />
```

You could also pass the image name as parameter to the controller action:

```
public class ImagesController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult SomeImage(string imageName)
    {
        var root = @"C:\Images\";
        var path = Path.Combine(root, imageName);
        path = Path.GetFullPath(path);
        if (!path.StartsWith(root))
        {
            // Ensure that we are serving file only inside the root folder
            // and block requests outside like "../web.config"
            throw new HttpException(403, "Forbidden");
        }

        return File(path, "image/jpeg");
    }
}
```

and in your view:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("SomeImage", "Images", new { image = "foo.jpg" })" alt="" />
```

Comment: I am very new to MVC3, what would that look like?

Comment: It would look like a controller action returning a FileResult. See my updated answer.

Comment: I'm using MVC4 and it doesn't work for me: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) What would be the cause? I definitely have the controller in place

Answer (score 0):

The above code was useful for me, with a change like this

```
 System.Web.UI.Page page = new System.Web.UI.Page();
 string filePath = page.Server.MapPath("~/Log/" + fileName);

        if (!filePath.StartsWith(filePath))

        {

            throw new HttpException(403, "Forbidden");
        }

        return File(filePath, "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=TableImportLog.csv");
```

}

the  file thrown to the user is with file name like this  "attachment;filename=TableImportLog.csv", but i want the file name as "TableErrorLog.csv"
need help for the same!